# How doing dropdown menu in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

How me doing dropdown menu for pages and child pages on wordpress 4.0, but wp_page_menu not working, wp_list_pages('title_li=') ?> show menu but not show child pages. please help?

Comment: Are you doing it from the backend ?

Comment: i add this code in header in templeta folder

Comment: Try this : `<?php wp_list_pages('title_li=&include=24'); ?>
<?php wp_list_pages('title_li=&child_of=24'); ?>`

Note: 24 is page number.You can do like this to get sub pages.

Comment: thanks, now showing page and her child page, but i need show Page - click and in dropdown list showing her child pages. how this doing?

Comment: Then you need to write JS for it.Like on hover of main page show sub page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    ul.menu { list-style: none outside none; padding: 0; margin: 0 10px; float: left; font-size: 13px;}
    ul.menu li { float: left; margin: 0; padding: 0 15px 0 0; position: relative; }
    ul.menu li a { padding: 9px 5px; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); display: block; text-decoration: none; float: left; display: block;}
    ul.menu li:hover { background: #A6CB1B; }
    .current-cat { background: #8BBF47; }
    ul.menu li span { width: 11px; height: 10px; float: left; background: url('/*url of your background or write color anme*/') -561px -78px no-repeat; margin: 11px 0 0 0;}
    ul.menu li ul.children {z-index:99; list-style: none outside none; position: absolute; left: 0; top: 31px; background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(51, 51, 51); margin: 0; padding: 0; display: none; float: left; width: 170px; border-bottom: 1px solid #F8C92D;}
    ul.menu li ul.children li { margin: 0; padding: 0; clear: both; width: 170px; border-top: 1px solid #F8C92D;}
    html ul.menu li ul.children li a { float: left; width: 145px; background: url('images/narga-sprites.png') -578px -162px no-repeat #A6CB1B; padding-left: 20px; }
    html ul.menu li ul.children li a:hover { background: url('/*url of your background or write color anme same as above*/') -578px -162px no-repeat #7BAF36; }
```

**NOTE**: This code is untested.Make sure to do necessary changes as per your needs.

Comment: Have you pasted it in your style.css?

Comment: Not true ?? I did not get you..What you exactly want ?

Comment: I have two pages in the menu next to the parent and child, I need to show only the parent, and when you hover over it a drop-down list of child pages

Comment: Give me some time.I will get back to you after finishing my to do list.